# Actions/Delegates in C# and Windows Phone 7 (using RestSharp)

Tags: windows-phone-8, restsharp

I'm writing a program with `RestSharp` on WP8, with LastFMSharp to be exact but I have to update the methods to `ExecuteAsync` since its WP. The problem with this is that where as before the Execute(request) returned a RestResponse, ExecuteAsync returns a RestRequestAsyncHandle. I need that RestResponse for my method. So how do I get it into the var response? Keep in mind the structure is

```
RestSharp.RestClient.ExecuteAsync<T>(RestSharp.IRestRequest,System.Action<RestSharp.IRestResponse<T>,RestSharp.RestRequestAsyncHandle>)
```

Thanks for the help!

Original:

```
public RestResponse<T> Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
{
     request.AddParameter("api_key", _apiKey);

     var response = _restClient.Execute<T>(request);
     RequestCount++;
     DataCount += response.RawBytes.Length;
     return response;
}
```

Changed (don't work not sure what callback is supposed to be):

```
public RestResponse<T> Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
{
         request.AddParameter("api_key", _apiKey);

        //var response = 
        _restClient.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
                        {
                            callback(response.Content);
                        });

        RequestCount++;
        DataCount += response.RawBytes.Length;
        return response;
}
```

callback initialize response? how do I make it do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't as the response doesn't happen until some time in the future, at which point the callback will be called.

As this is Windows Phone 8, try using the [`async\await` pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx).

Comment: In particular, you can use `TaskCompletionSource<RestResponse<T>>` to wrap `ExecuteAsync` and its callback into a method that returns `Task<RestResponse<T>>`.

Comment: ok thanks guys ill post back if i run into issues. I guess the implications of using async hadnt hit me.